# Java threads:Comminucation between 3 java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have 3 threads,

A thread which downloads audio and the audio schedule object from the internet.
A thread which plays the audio according to the audio schedule.
And a web socket "notification" listener that listens for messages that say we have to download new audio and schedule as our current one is outdated.

The program flow is as follows:
On application startup: The ScheduleDownloader starts,downloads audio and schedule file.Once completed it needs to tell the audio player "hey the files are ready and here is the schedule" and it doesnt need to do anything for now

The audio player starts and continuously loops with no exit condition.
The web socket listener starts,when it gets a message.It should tell the schedule downloader "You need to start again as there is new files you need to download",it doesnt need to send any data to the schedule downloaded,just start it up again.The music should remain playing.Once it is done it should now restart the audio player thread with the new schedule.

Here is what I have so far,I am not sure how to get ScheduleDownloader to tell AudioPlayer "the files are ready and you need to start,here is the schedule"  or "you need to restart with the new schedule,here it is" or how to get the listener to say "ScheduleDownloader you need to start again"

```
public class ScheduleDownloader extends Thread {
private Thread t;
private String threadName;

   String username;
 String password;

    public ScheduleDownloader(String username,String password,String threadName){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.threadName= threadName;
    }
public void start () {
    System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread (this, threadName);
        t.start ();
    }}
public void run() {
    try {
        Schedule schedule= null;
        while(schedule == null){
            System.out.println("Searching for schedule");
           schedule= getTodaysSchedule();
        }
        System.out.println("Schedule Found");
        boolean result = false;
        while(result == false){
            result = downloadFiles(schedule);
        }
        System.out.println("Files Downloaded");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Schedule getTodaysSchedule() throws IOException {
        Schedule schedule = null;
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials
                = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password);
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);


        String url = "http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/today";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build(); //Use this instead
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
  //read content response body
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("sorry error:" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } else {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            //change json response to java objects


            Gson gson = new Gson();
             schedule = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(result),Schedule.class);

}
        return schedule;

}
public static boolean downloadFiles(Schedule schedule) {
 //get the music
    for(int i =0;i<schedule.getMusicScheduleItems().size();i++){
    downloadOneFile("shoutloudaudio","music/" +
            schedule.getMusicScheduleItems().get(i).getMusic().getId()+
            "-music.wav");
    }
    //get the advertisements
    for(int i =0;i<schedule.getAdvertisementScheduleItems().size();i++){
        downloadOneFile("shoutloudaudio","advertisements/" +
                schedule.getAdvertisementScheduleItems().get(i).getAdvertisement().getId()+
                "-advertisement.wav");
    }

    return true;


}

public static boolean downloadOneFile(String bucketName,String key) {
    if( new File(key.split("/")[1]).isFile()){
        //check if we have it already and dont need to download it

        System.out.println(key + " alraeady exits");
        return true;
    }
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "removed",
            "removed"
    );
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();
    S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject(bucketName, key);
    S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
    InputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(
            inputStream);
    File file = new File(key.split("/")[1]);//save the file as whats after the / in key
    OutputStream writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    int read = -1;
try {
while ((read = reader.read()) != -1) {
    writer.write(read);
}

writer.flush();
writer.close();
}catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
    return true;
}
}
```

AudioPlayer

```
public class AudioPlayer extends Thread {
Long currentFrameMusic;
Long currentFrameAdvertisement;
Clip clipMusic;
Clip clipAdvertisement;
private Thread t;

 // current status of clip
 String statusMusic;
 String statusAdvertisement;

static AudioInputStream musicInputStream;
static AudioInputStream advertisementInputStream;
static String filePath;
Schedule schedule;

 // constructor to initialize streams and clip
public AudioPlayer(Schedule schedule)
        throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
        IOException, LineUnavailableException
{
    //setup audio stream for music first
    // create AudioInputStream object
this.schedule = schedule;
    appendMusicFiles(schedule);

    // create clip reference
    clipMusic = AudioSystem.getClip();

    // open audioInputStream to the clip
    clipMusic.open(musicInputStream);

    clipMusic.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

public void run(){
    playMusic();
    try {
        checkShouldWePlayAnAdvertisement();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void start(){
    t = new Thread (this, "AudioPlayerThread");
    t.start ();
}
public void start2() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
playMusic();
checkShouldWePlayAnAdvertisement();
}
public void playMusic()
{
    //start the clip
    clipMusic.start();

    statusMusic = "play";
}

// Method to pause the audio
public void pauseMusic()
{
    if (statusMusic.equals("paused"))
    {
        System.out.println("audio is already paused");
        return;
    }
    this.currentFrameMusic =
            this.clipMusic.getMicrosecondPosition();
    clipMusic.stop();
    statusMusic = "paused";
    System.out.println("pausing music");
}

// Method to resume the audio
public void resumeAudioMusic() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
        IOException, LineUnavailableException
{
    if (statusMusic.equals("play"))
    {
        System.out.println("Audio is already "+
                "being played");
        return;
    }
    clipMusic.close();
    resetAudioStreamMusic();
    clipMusic.setMicrosecondPosition(currentFrameMusic);
    System.out.println("resuming music");
    this.playMusic();
}

// Method to restart the audio
public void restartMusic() throws IOException, LineUnavailableException,
        UnsupportedAudioFileException
{
    clipMusic.stop();
    clipMusic.close();
    resetAudioStreamMusic();
    currentFrameMusic = 0L;
    clipMusic.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
    this.playMusic();
}

// Method to stop the audio
public void stopMusic() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
        IOException, LineUnavailableException
{
    currentFrameMusic = 0L;
    clipMusic.stop();
    clipMusic.close();
}
public void resetAudioStreamMusic() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException,
        LineUnavailableException
{
   clipMusic =  AudioSystem.getClip();
   appendMusicFiles(schedule);

    // open audioInputStream to the clip
    clipMusic.open(musicInputStream);

    clipMusic.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

public static void appendMusicFiles(Schedule schedule) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    //add the first audio file to stream
    AudioInputStream appendedFiles = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new File(schedule.getMusicScheduleItems().get(0).getMusic()
                    .getId() + "-music.wav"));
    //loop through an combine
    for(int i =1;i<schedule.getMusicScheduleItems().size();i++){

        File file=  new File(schedule.getMusicScheduleItems().get(i).getMusic()
                .getId() + "-music.wav");
        AudioInputStream toBeAppended = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        //append them
        appendedFiles =
                new AudioInputStream(
                        new SequenceInputStream(appendedFiles, toBeAppended),
                        appendedFiles.getFormat(),
                        appendedFiles.getFrameLength() + toBeAppended.getFrameLength());
    }
    musicInputStream = appendedFiles;

}

//advertisement methods

public void playAdvertisements() throws LineUnavailableException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    clipAdvertisement = AudioSystem.getClip();

    // open audioInputStream to the clip
    clipAdvertisement.open(advertisementInputStream);

    System.out.println(clipAdvertisement.getMicrosecondLength());
    //start the clip
    clipAdvertisement.start();
    Thread.sleep(clipAdvertisement.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
    statusAdvertisement = "play";

    System.out.println("playing advertisements");
}

// Method to pause the audio
public void pauseAdvertisements()
{
    if (statusAdvertisement.equals("paused"))
    {
        System.out.println("audio is already paused");
        return;
    }
    this.currentFrameAdvertisement =
            this.clipAdvertisement.getMicrosecondPosition();
    clipAdvertisement.stop();
    statusAdvertisement = "paused";
}

// Method to resume the audio
public void resumeAudioAdvertisement() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
        IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
    if (statusAdvertisement.equals("play"))
    {
        System.out.println("Audio is already "+
                "being played");
        return;
    }
    clipAdvertisement.close();
    resetAudioStreamAdvertisement();
    clipAdvertisement.setMicrosecondPosition(currentFrameMusic);
    this.playAdvertisements();
}

// Method to restart the audio
public void restartAdvertisement() throws IOException, LineUnavailableException,
        UnsupportedAudioFileException, InterruptedException {
    clipAdvertisement.stop();
    clipAdvertisement.close();
    resetAudioStreamAdvertisement();
    currentFrameAdvertisement = 0L;
    clipAdvertisement.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
    this.playAdvertisements();
}

// Method to stop the audio
public void stopAdvertisement() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
        IOException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
    currentFrameAdvertisement = 0L;
    clipAdvertisement.stop();
    clipAdvertisement.close();
    System.out.println("stopping advertisement");
}
public void resetAudioStreamAdvertisement() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException,
        LineUnavailableException
{
    advertisementInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new File(filePath).getAbsoluteFile());
    clipAdvertisement.open(musicInputStream);
    clipAdvertisement.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

public static void appendAdvertisementFiles(List<Advertisement> advertisementItems) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    //add the first audio file to stream
    AudioInputStream appendedFiles = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new File(advertisementItems.get(0)
                    .getId() + "-advertisement.wav"));
    //loop through an combine
    for(int i =1;i<advertisementItems.size();i++){

        File file=  new File(advertisementItems.get(i)
                .getId() + "-advertisement.wav");
        AudioInputStream toBeAppended = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        //append them
        appendedFiles =
                new AudioInputStream(
                        new SequenceInputStream(appendedFiles, toBeAppended),
                        appendedFiles.getFormat(),
                        appendedFiles.getFrameLength() + toBeAppended.getFrameLength());
    }
    advertisementInputStream = appendedFiles;

}

     public void checkShouldWePlayAnAdvertisement() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<String> playedAtTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Advertisement> advertisementsToBePlayed = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean found;
    //played at times is used to keep track of what time we played advertisements
    //so when the loop reruns and the time hasnt changed it doesnt play it again
    while(true){
        found = false;
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
      String timeHHMM =zdt.toString().substring(11,16);
     for(int i =0;i<schedule.getAdvertisementScheduleItems().size();i++)
  {







    if(schedule.getAdvertisementScheduleItems().get(i).getTimes()
    .contains(timeHHMM))
      {
//this item should be played now
if(playedAtTimes.contains(timeHHMM)){
    //we already played this,but the time hasnt changed when the loop ran again
}else{
advertisementsToBePlayed.add(schedule.getAdvertisementScheduleItems().get(i).getAdvertisement());
found = true;
}
}
}
 if(found== true){
playedAtTimes.add(timeHHMM);
appendAdvertisementFiles(advertisementsToBePlayed);
pauseMusic();
playAdvertisements();
stopAdvertisement();

resumeAudioMusic();
}

    }
 }
 }
```

IotClient(part of listener)

```
public class IotClient extends Thread {
 Thread t;
 String username;
public IotClient(String username)  {
    this.username = username;
}
 public void run(){
 String clientEndpoint = "removve";       // replace <prefix> and <region> with your own
 String clientId = "1";                              // replace with your own client ID. Use unique client IDs for concurrent connections.

// AWS IAM credentials could be retrieved from AWS Cognito, STS, or other secure sources
AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, "remove", "remove");

    // optional parameters can be set before connect()
try {
    client.connect();
} catch (AWSIotException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
AWSIotQos qos = AWSIotQos.QOS0;
AWSIotTopic topic = new MyTopic("schedule/"+ username, qos);
try {
    client.subscribe(topic, true);
} catch (AWSIotException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while(true){

}
}
public void start(){
if (t == null) {
    t = new Thread (this, "IotClientThread");
    t.start ();
}
   }
```

MyTopic(part of listener)

```
public class MyTopic extends AWSIotTopic {
public MyTopic(String topic, AWSIotQos qos) {
    super(topic, qos);
}

@Override
public void onMessage(AWSIotMessage message) {
    System.out.println("Message recieved from topic: "+ message.getStringPayload());
}
}
```

Comment: Side issue: You almost *never* want to extend Thread but rather implement `Runnable` or `Callable<V>` depending on your need.

Comment: Yeah I realise extending threads limits what you from inheriting other things but for my use-case here its fine

Comment: It's not just that as it also limits what you can do with them. Now you can't use an ExecutorService or Thread pools,... Just don't do this.

Comment: Also this type of question is often an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question since "threads" don't communicate -- *objects* do.

Comment: Just a hint, this is way too much specific code for such a generic question, and your question should be stated earlier and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Threads communicate via shared references to messages 'containers' objects in memory. That could be as simple as mere mutable field of a shared instance of some class, or more typical collection like list, map, but especially queues.

ArrayBlockingQueue is a good shared reference. There would be a queue for each message direction from one thread to another. If you had 3 threads that could truly talks to each other, you would have 3 pairs, thus 6 queues (2 for each pair). However, it is often the case that messages flow only in one direction, so you might save a few.

Now, the core of these communications is a mechanism to wait for some message (reader/consumer), and notify when a message is pushed (writer/producer).

Of course, you can learn (penty of tutorials out there) from the bottom going up, from the primitive wait/notify, or you can jump into classes like ArrayBlockingQueue which abstract the wait/notify of messages into take()/put(). I recommend starting from the bottom as things will make sense more rapidly when you meet other classes in java.util.concurrent.*

I cannot give you code, it would be largely not understandable at your level without having learned the basic of ITC (inter-thread communications).

Good learning!

PS: there are many pitfalls on the way, like thread safety, atomicity of writes, lock free algorithms, deadlocks, livelocks, starvation. Just the multi queue example above can lead to circular dependencies on message arrival, particularly when queue get full and block. This is a science!